# Что означает D(W/M)AU?

Tags: android

Здравствуйте, поступило задание интегрировать в приложение flurry от yahoo.
Одним из пунктов является "Определение D(W/M)AU", проблема в том что я не представляю что это....Прошу вашей помощи.
И еще вопрос, нужно ли для сбора статистики в каждой активити инициализировать flurry, или дотаточно только в главной активити?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Значение DAU/WAU/MAU
Это показатель «увлекательности» игры, который говорит о том, сколько людей играет в онлан-игру каждый день.

DAU (daily active users) – это число уникальных пользователей, которые запустили игру хотя бы раз в сутки.
WAU (weekly active users) – это число уникальных пользователей, которые запустили игру хотя бы раз в неделю.
MAU (monthly active users) – это число уникальных пользователей, которые запустили игру хотя бы раз в месяц.

Величина DAU/WAU/MAU характеризует долю всех игроков, которые играют в игру каждый день. Чем выше это значение, тем больше вовлеченных игроков, тем больше шансов, что игроки будут покупать внутриигровой контент.

Считается, что если **DAU/MAU** (отношение Д к М) больше 0.2, игру можно считать успешной.

Что касается вопроса

> нужно ли для сбора статистики в каждой активити инициализировать
>   flurry, или дотаточно только в главной активити?

Скорее всего, нужно в каждой инитить. Но нужно точно посмотреть, что говорится в документации.